# Meteor: How to run check() when there are no arguments

Tags: javascript, meteor

If there are no values in the `{ }`, what should I check for?
Theres an error on my command prompt: `Did not check all arguments`.

Referring to the docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check), doesnt explain on no arguments. Only in cases where say argument = postId, then check is `check(postId, String)` for example.

Im looking at specifically this publish. If no arguments, shouldnt there be no checks? Why is it throwing me this error?

```
  Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
    return Posts.find({});
  });
```

While it does not cause any major crashes, appreciate any help here.

Comment: Remove this empty object, `return Posts.find()` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Sindis, your method worked!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you got this error, you may have added `audit-arguments-checks` package or something like that. But this package only require to have arguments checked on method calls, not white subscribing.
2. Even if your publication or method does not show arguments, subscribtion or client method calls may have send some.

Comment: On 1) "This package causes Meteor to require that all arguments passed to methods **and publish functions** are checked" (emph mine) http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks